# Grainy button transform in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-transitions, transform

I am trying to transform a `button`, but it is really grainy (During the transform) in firefox. 
Can someone take a look, the code is below... and the js fiddle link is attached here https://jsfiddle.net/L3f9cy7g/1/

As I said. The issue is only in `firefox`, and I think it has something to do with anti-aliasing. We tried switching it to a 3d transform, and adjusting the `z-index` to prevent the firefox browser from messing with the animation. No luck so far.

```
<div class="closePop">
<p></p>
</div>

body{background:black;}
.closePop {
    right: -5px;
    top: -5px;
    height: 28px;
    background-color: #f68d1e;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 29px;
    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
}
.closePop p {
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 4px;
}
 .closePop:hover p:after {
    content:':(';
    transition:contentArea 3s ease-out rotate .3s ease-out;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: translateZ(1px) rotate(0deg);
}
.closePop p:after {
    content: 'X';
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: translateZ(1px) rotate(90deg);
}
.closePop:hover {
    border-radius: 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
        transform: translateZ(1px) rotate(90deg);
}
 .closePop p {
    transition: contentArea .3s ease-out rotate .3s ease-out;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add a transparent outline attribute,

```
outline: 1px solid transparent;
```

Comment: Help with the border for sure. There is still a movement at the end of animation, but you did for sure answer what was being asked.

Comment: Added your fix to the fiddle to Show ya.

Comment: Yeah, if you look at the animation side by side in chrome and firefox with the fix, you can still see a tiny difference in how the 'X' moves.

Comment: That I can deal with... That grainy animation I could not. ha